# How to fetch the the second row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query below which is used to make a view. This query pulls the latest record of the `report_id`.

One report_id can have multiple unique `report_info_id`

```html
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.report_id) t.temporal_start_date,
    t.report_id,
    t.report_info_id,
    t.status
   FROM reports_infos t
  ORDER BY t.report_id, t.temporal_start_date DESC;
```

This results in data something like

```html
temporal_start_date    |report_id|report_info_id|status                 |
-----------------------|---------|--------------|-----------------------|
    2006-09-22 00:00:00|       49|         20435|Validated              |
    2006-08-02 00:00:00|       89|         25782|Validated              |
    2006-11-13 00:00:00|      108|         20436|Validated              |
2020-12-09 09:27:29.214|      130|         31755|Edited after validation|
```

Lets take the example of last record  where report_id= 130

```html
 select report_info_id , report_id , temporal_start_date, temporal_end_date,status  from reports_infos where report_id=130 order by temporal_start_date desc
```

```html
report_info_id|report_id|temporal_start_date    |temporal_end_date      |status                 |
--------------|---------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
         31755|      130|2020-12-09 09:27:29.214|                       |Edited after validation|
         29714|      130|2020-11-20 14:50:44.227|2020-12-09 09:27:29.215|Validated              |
         29713|      130|2020-11-20 14:49:27.088|2020-11-20 14:50:44.228|Edited after validation|
         25788|      130|    2006-03-20 00:00:00|2020-11-20 14:49:27.089|Validated              |
```

Now it is required that in first query I want such data if the status is "Edited after validation"  then pull the second row of that report_id

Expected result

```html
temporal_start_date    |report_id|report_info_id|status                 |
-----------------------|---------|--------------|-----------------------|
    2006-09-22 00:00:00|       49|         20435|Validated              |
    2006-08-02 00:00:00|       89|         25782|Validated              |
    2006-11-13 00:00:00|      108|         20436|Validated              |
2020-11-20 14:50:44.227|      130|         29714|Validated|
```

Comment: Use `row_number()` less than or equal to 2 instead of `distinct on`

Comment: Just add `WHERE status <> 'Edited after validation'` to your query. or `WHERE status = 'Validated'`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov  This worked for me. Kindly add this reply in answer . I will accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem you need not the second row in each group as such, but a row that satisfies an additional criteria. You want to skip the row with status "Edited after validation". To do that you can simply add a `WHERE` filter to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.report_id) 
    t.temporal_start_date,
    t.report_id,
    t.report_info_id,
    t.status
FROM reports_infos t
WHERE t.status <> 'Edited after validation'
ORDER BY t.report_id, t.temporal_start_date DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.report_id) 
    t.temporal_start_date,
    t.report_id,
    t.report_info_id,
    t.status
FROM reports_infos t
WHERE t.status = 'Validated'
ORDER BY t.report_id, t.temporal_start_date DESC;
```

Both queries produce the same result if `status` can be only either `Edited after validation` or `Validated`. If `status` can have some other values as well, pick the variant that suits the necessary logic.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY report_id
                                 ORDER BY temporal_start_date DESC) rn
    FROM reports_info
)

SELECT temporal_start_date, report_id, report_info_id, status
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 2;
```